# How to disable the mapping between two activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[image: Filter Emp File from Metadata activity]

There are 4 Files on my Folder name Company Filter1 will filter file starting from Emp, Filter2 will filter file starting from Payroll.
By mistake i connect filter2 activity with Get Metadata1 activity. Can you please tell me how to disconnect them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select that link and click delete from key board. That would delete the link between them.

Another way would be right click on that link :

[image]